# Употребление слова "заморозки"

Tags: лексика

*Прогноз погоды на  8 января: ночью −8,  утром −9. Завтра резкое похолодание,возможны заморозки.*

Не раз читала подобное в прогнозе погоды. Обычно после оттепели (сегодня, 7 января, была плюсовая температура). Всегда такое употребление привлекает внимание, мне оно кажется неправильным. Я считаю, что заморозки могут быть в теплое время, никак не в январе. Как вы думаете?

Comment: Конечно, в сочетании с предыдущим текстом "ночью −8, утром −9", возможность *заморозков* изумляет, мягко говоря. Заморозки — это переходы (на *местах* и в регионах) из плюса в минус, *первое грозных обвалов движенье*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Значение слова указано в словаре.
   ЗАМОРОЗКИ, ед.  заморозок. Легкий  утренний мороз осенью или весной. Ранние з. 3. на почве.
   Таким образом, заморозки могут быть только на границе  осень-зима, зима-весна.
2. Значение слова интересно соотнести со значением входящих морфем. У Ефремовой есть похожая схема образования: двор – задворки, в этом случае приставка ЗА имеет значение «позади, ниже». В нашем случае ее вероятное значение за пределами «настоящего мороза», то есть зимы.

Comment: >В нашем случае ее вероятное значение за пределами «настоящего мороза», то есть зимы.

Скорее, наоборот: *прихват* из тепла настоящего мороза. Ползучее наступление осенью и агонизирующий реванш поздней весной. Забереги (начало заледенения воды) — в том же смысле.

Comment: Январь - не весна и не осень, а самый разгар зимы.

Comment: Речь как раз идет о том, что слово употреблено неправильно: заморозков в январе не может быть.

Comment: И я о том же. Но это не единичное употребление. В прогнозе погоды такое слышала не единожды. Вот и интересно, для синоптиков (или метеорологов?) это ошибка или профессионализм?

Comment: Это они между собой могут разговаривать на профессиональном языке, а сообщения в эфире должны делаться на правильном русском.

Comment: Заморозки  могут  быть  только  летом  или  близко  к  лету.  А  зимой  могут  быть  только  оттепели.  Заморозки  -  это  кратковременные  минусовые  температуры,  ночные  или  утренние,  обычно  на  почве,  в  низинах.

Answer (score 0):

Может, это не минус, а тире? Тогда после плюсовых температур возможны и заморозки на почве. В зимнее время, конечно,странно смотрится такое выражение, но ведь морозом не назовёшь температуру около нуля - нуль? По-другому как-то и не скажешь.

Comment: Нет, не тире, а минус. Просто 7 января (один только день) - плюсовая температура днем, а восьмого - минусовая. И это они (синоптики) называют заморозками. Я понимаю, что седьмого - оттепель. Но все остальные дни мороз, причем тут заморозки?

Answer (score 0):

Заморозки - отрицательная температура ночью при положительной температуре днём. Иногда в это слово вкладывают другое значение: ночная температура -1-3 градуса независимо от температуры днём.